# socket: local server port as .search-agent

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am new to socket programing and am running server and client, examples from python docs, locally

server:

```
import socket

HOST_PORT = ("127.0.0.1", 1234)

socket_obj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_obj.bind(HOST_PORT)
socket_obj.listen(3)
print(f"server running at {HOST_PORT}")

while True:
    client_soc, addr = socket_obj.accept()
    print(f"client: {addr}")
    client_soc.send(b"hell0 from server")
```

client:

```
import socket

SERVER_HOST_PORT = ("127.0.0.1", 1234)

socket_obj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_obj.connect(SERVER_HOST_PORT)
#data = socket_obj.recv(1024)

while True:
    data = socket_obj.recv(10)
    print(f"got data from server: {data}")
```

I am trying to find out the details of both client and server socket via **netstat**

client address is appearing as `localhost.58724` which is correct, but of server, it is displaying `localhost.search-agent` (which is running at port `1234`)

why  `.search-agent` is coming instead of the port number of the server (1234)

---> UPDATE (find the process by port)

```
$ lsof -i tcp:1234

    COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    Python  3013 naveen    3u  IPv4 0xff691590c7ecdff      0t0  TCP localhost:search-agent (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Please don't post external links to source code when you can just post it here.

Comment: @navyad two questions (please post the answers to these questions in your post, not in the comments): what OS are you using? how are you running `netcat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce this on macOS 11.4, and the reason this is happening is that, at least on Linux and macOS, `search-agent` is the symbolic name for port `1234`, aka it's the process that usually uses that port on those systems.

Run `netcat` with `-n` to show the actual numbers instead of the symbolic names, e.g. `127.0.0.1:1234` instead of `localhost:search-agent`.